# App se cierra al cargar sdt en IOS Genexus 17 U2

Tags: ios, genexus

Tengo un Panel que carga en el evento `ClientStart` un SDT con los contactos del cliente. Cuando el SDT se carga con mas de 26 contactos la app se cierra, pero en Android funciona perfectamente.

Muestro parte del código

```
&InformacionContactos = Contacts.GetAllContacts()       
for &InformacionContacto in &InformacionContactos
    &InformacionContacto.Phone = &InformacionContacto.Phone.ReplaceRegEx('(^)[(\(\)\-\ )]*(\+)*(57)*|[(\(\)\-\ )]', '')
    if &InformacionContacto.Phone.StartsWith('3') and &InformacionContacto.Phone.Length() >= 10
        &Contactos = new()
        &Contactos.NombreCompleto = &InformacionContacto.DisplayName.ToUpper()
        &Contactos.Celular = &InformacionContacto.Phone
        &SDTContactos.Add(&Contactos)
    endif
endfor
```

El problema es cuando se está asignando los datos en el SDT &SDTContactos

Comment: ¿podrías agregar información del error que te da?

Comment: Pudiste solucionar? me pasa algo parecido y aún no doy con la respuesta